MC Fight with magic academy instructor
It's an isekai manga about an ancient sorcerer, his mother is a commoner and his father is a nobleman, his mother dies and he goes to live with his father and his brother and sister from another mother. At some point in the manga an instructor from Magic Academy mistreats him because he is a commoner and forces his half-brother (who gets angry that he is accepting to be treated that way) to do the same.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you have any idea where?  Was it black-and-white or in colour?

I'm sorry for the delay in responding to you. I think about two years ago.It's a manga (black and white). I unfortunately don't remember the website I read it on I also remember that after the fight between the MC and hi instructor, his older brother goes to magic academy and he stays with his half-sister. Then there's time Skip and the MC goes too Magic academy

by "ancient sorcerer", do you mean someone who uses "ancient" magic, or an old sorcerer? Because he sounds like a child - was he reincarnated within this world? Or originally from a world of magic and transmigrates to another world as a child?
